# Написать протокол на java?

Tags: java, сеть, udp

Подскажите как написать протокол на java, для передачи коротких данных (также интересна передача Rreal-time и Stream трафика). Передача должна осуществляться на основе транспортного протокола UDP.

Comment: протокол это алгоритм взаимодействия двух и более обьектов, можете и сами придумать все что угодно. но для того чтоб избавить себя от банальных ошибок лучше все таки почитать о уже существующих протоколах :)

Comment: Ну дык прочитайте любой RFC, описывающий протокол поверх UDP и опишите свой по аналогии. Потом за ящик Хеннеси это воплотят в Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну а чего тут особо сильно думать то? Транспортный протокол известен/задан UPD - соответственно теперь надо озаботиться следующим уровнем стека протоколов ([согласно великой могучей науке](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)) - фактически прикладным уровнем.

На одной стороне сервер принимаем/посылает массив байтов, а на другой стороне клиент аналогично принимает/посылает массив байтов.

Обычно массив байтов полагается структурировать в виде структуры/класса, например:

```
public class MyProtocolData
{
    private String header;   //некий заголовок показывающий чего шлем или что шлем?
    private String senderId;  //идентификатор отправителя (если надо)
    private String addressId; //идентификатор получателя (если надо)
    private int chunkId;      //очередность куска данных
    private int dataLength;   //длина данных
    private byte[] data;      //данные
}
```

В общем все ограничено только вашей фантазией.

**Update**
Посылка байтов также лишена романтики и выглядит примерно так (грубо):

```
byte[] sendData;
DatagramSocket mySocket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
DatagramPacket sendPacket =new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, address, port);
mySocket.send(sendPacket);
```

Comment: @Barmaley понятно что надо создавать структуру, а как мне передавать данные ?

Comment: см. апдейт

Comment: Передавать данные - как раз очень просто. Самое сложное - учесть особенности потокового трафика. Придумав формат сообщений (например, запросов клиента и ответов сервера), написав функции приема/отправки дейтаграмм, разбора входящих сообщений и формирования исходящих, вы получите что-то вроде HTTP, но никак не реалтаймовый протокол.

Comment: @Barmaley мне надо преобразовать мой объект MyProtocolData в массив байтов и я могу его передавать, да ?

Comment: @northerner подскажите тогда как и что мне сделать ? ну или хотя бы что почитать (может уже кто реализовывал прикладные протоколы на java и можно посмотреть код ?)

Comment: @pol, на самом деле всё зависит от задачи, может быть вам тонкости передачи потокового трафика и ни к чему, особенно, если это учебное задание (в формулировке ведь не написано). Тогда действительно достаточно реализовать идею @Barmaley. Ну, подкину еще ссылку на материалы первой части курса [Internet Programming with Java](http://www.nakov.com/inetjava/lectures/part-1-sockets/). Там есть примеры реализации.

Но если вы все-таки задумали реализовать реалтайм - всё сложнее. Например, нужно думать о реализации QoS.

Comment: 2 @pol автор вы явно невнимательно читали мой каммент. протокол это не есть что-то физическое, это алгоритм (по другому правило, схема) взаимодействия двух "обьектов". если у вас есть клиент который постоянно шлет пакеты серверу это уже есть протокол. 

напр. в TCP перед тем как открывается соединение стороны предварительно обмениваются служебными пакетами (чтоб обе стороны были готовы к созданию соединения). когда соединение создано пересылаются данные, опять же каждый пакет кроме полезной, имеет служебную информацию, для того чтоб можно было переслать его еще раз в случае потерь

Comment: продолжение: если все это вам нужно вкрутить с помощью UDP то вам нужно побеспокоится о таких вещах:
1) разделение информации на пакеты  
2) сжатие + помехоустойчивое кодирование
3) валидация и склеивание пакетов при получении

служебную информацию которую надо добавлять:
1) идентификатор пакета (заодно и будет номером пакета при передачи связанного набора данных)
2) "флаги" - в резерве (я б оставил 1 байт на всякий случай, мало ли)
4) последнее что добавляется к пакету это его контрольная сумма. если у премника не совпадает crc пакета или же данных то он запрашывает передачу еще раз

Comment: Сомнительно, что нужна реализация помехоустойчивого кодирования и контрольная сумма пакета. UDP в своих заголовках использует контрольную сумму и сам отбрасывает поврежденные пакеты.

--

В принципе   есть две проблемы с UDP. Первая (для LAN не наблюдается) в том, что пакеты могут приходить не в порядке отправки.

Вторая серьезней. При высокой нагрузке пакеты отбрасывваются на уровне драйвера, не попадая в очередь к сокету.

@pol, разработка прикладного уровня протокола возможна только при ясном понимании семантики обработки  и природы исходных данных (как они появляются в системе)

Comment: @jmu, автору вопроса не надо имитировать все возможности TCP, используя транспорт UDP. Да, так делают иногда, например, в протоколе NFS, но тут другой случай, например:

> если у премника не совпадает crc пакета или же данных то он запрашывает передачу еще раз

При передаче мультимедийного потока чаще всего повторять передачу пакета бессмысленно - поезд ушел - лучше забыть про потерянный пакет или отбросить битый. В противном случае будет хуже: колебания задержки (jitter) больно бьют по качеству VoIP.

Comment: @pol, не знаю, что у Вас за задача, не сочтите этот совет издевательством, попробуйте ознакомиться с GSM (да, сотовая телефония). 

Из используемых там алгоритмов очень много интересных идей можно вытащить и возможно адаптировать для обмена по UDP.

Comment: @avp спасибо за совет) задача у меня чисто учебная)

Answer (score 2):

[RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt)

> Applications typically run RTP on top
> of UDP to make use of its multiplexing
> and checksum services; both protocols
> contribute parts of the transport
> protocol functionality.

[О протоколе RTP в базе знаний Asterisk (кратко, на русском языке)](http://asterisk.ru/knowledgebase/RTP)